# Junit Test implementation of configure() method of Guice AbstractModule

Tags: junit, guice

I have a module which implements `configure()` method of Guice `AbstractModule` class. I `bind()` object instances in this method simply as follows:

```
bind(Command.class)
.annotatedWith(Names.named("commandSpringBean"))
.toProvider(
    SpringIntegration.fromSpring(Command.class, "commandSpringBean"));
```

How can I write a JUnit to test this method?

Comment: What do you want to write unit tests for? You don't need to write unit tests to see if Guice is working, that's the job of the developers of Guice.

Comment: @Progman Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58031425/write-junit-for-guice-bindings-of-spring-beans

Comment: What is the difference between this question and the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58031425/write-junit-for-guice-bindings-of-spring-beans? You can use the `Injector.getInstance()` method to get an instance or use the `Injector.getBindings()` method to get all the bindings registered in Guice.

Comment: @Progman Can you describe this in a unit test?

Comment: Depending on how you use Guice you can use `Guice.createInjector()` to get/create your injector and use methods like `getInstance()` and `getBindings()` to see, what type is registered.

Comment: While writing the unit test I keep getting errors during instance creation. So I asked how would you write a junit for the function mentioned in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58031425/write-junit-for-guice-bindings-of-spring-beans